# Pagination for custom query returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, 404-error

For a project I have created a custom post type called "episodes", which is registered like this.

```
 register_post_type( 'episodes',
array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Episodes' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Episode' )
  ),
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => false,
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'episodes'),
)
);
```

I have also created a page called episodes. The idea is that I want a page with some basic information and underneath a grid with 8 episodes which can be clicked through using pagination. To be clear, the content of the episodes page should alway show, even on page 2 or 3 of the grid.

To achieve this I created a `page-episodes.php` file, copied the content of `page.php` and added the following code to the page:

```
<?php 
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'episodes',
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'paged'          => $paged,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>

    <div class="row">
<?php if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-3 episode">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
        <span class="episodeNumber"><?php echo get_field("episode_number", $post->ID)?></span>
        <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 pagination">
            <?php 
                echo paginate_links();
            ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

But whenever I use the pagination and go to `/episodes/page/2` for example the page returns the `404.php` page.

I hope I have given you enough information, if not please ask. I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does this for you. You shouldn't need a custom Page template or custom query and pagination.

Just set `'has_archive'` to `true` when registering the post type. Then you automatically get `/episodes` and `/episodes/page/X`.

Then you just need to create `archive-afleveringen.php` for the template, and in that template use the functions for the main query:

```
<?php if( have_posts()) : while( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

You also don't need to create your own query or used `paged` at all.

Comment: I would like to have the content above the grid/list with episodes editable in the backend, is this possible if I use the archive page?